# Xcode 4.5 - Error while trying to install previous simulators

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I want to install previous versions of the iOS simulator on my machine so I can support for iOS 5 as well as 6. I went to the dropdown menu to install the other simulators, but when I try to download the simulators for 5.1 and 5.0, I get the error:

```
Failed to install "iOS 5.1 Simulator"
CSSM_ERRCODE_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Now I have the problem of when I download it, Xcode gives me another error, saying

```
authentication is required to install these packages
```

What's going on now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like an error associated with password issues. When you attempted to install the simulators and it asked for your Admin Password, you may have mistyped it. Try again.

Comment: but it never asked me for any passwords...Although I changed my login password after I installed it, so that's probably it. Where would I go to change that?

Comment: Changing the password AFTER installing it is not going to be the problem. Try installing the simulators again.

Comment: It's ok. I was trying to install them while Xcode was still open, and thinking I had a different password, but after I restarted it, and tried to download the simulators, it asked me for my password. Thanks!

Comment: I have a new problem. It's in the question :(

Comment: Im not sure what that is all about. Still sounds like a password problem. And it also sounds like my original answer, correctly answered your original question and you should mark my answer as correct Ask a different question specifying the details of the new situation.  :)

Comment: Sorry about that, for some reason (and I feel like a complete idiot now) after restarting the computer it installed fine. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: No problem dude, it happens to all of us :)